# Cannot import matplotlib after installing pyparsing, dateuil, six and numpy

Tags: python, matplotlib

As title, I cannot import matplotlib...

And here is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('picture.jpg',0)
f = np.fft.fft2(img)
fshift = np.fft.fftshift(f)
magnitude_spectrum = 20*np.log(np.abs(fshift))

plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img, cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Input Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(magnitude_spectrum, cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Magnitude Spectrum'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

Here is the error message:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
>
>    File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
>    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
>
>    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line
> 138, in <module>
>
> import pyparsing
>
>    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 3478, in
> <module>
>
>     _escapedPunc = Word( _bslash, r"\[]-*.$+^?()~ ", exact=2 ).setParseAction(lambda s,l,t:t[0][1])
>
>    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 948, in
> setParseAction
>
>     self.parseAction = list(map(_trim_arity, list(fns)))
>
>    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 808, in
> _trim_arity
>     this_line = extract_stack()[-1]
>
>    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 793, in
> extract_stack
>
>     return [(frame_summary.filename, frame_summary.lineno)]
>
>  AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'filename'
> ```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It's a pyparsing issue:

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/6399

Just wait for fix. Or you can upgrade python to 3.5

Comment: Can I downgrade pyparsing to solve this issue temporarily?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had install the newest pyparsing(2.1.3) and this issue is fixed !

Answer (score 2):

The error has occurred due to the recent version of `pyparsing` being in conflict with `matplotlib`, which pip has picked up.

The workaround would be to: `pip install pyparsing==2.1.1` followed by `pip install matplotlib`

Comment: Can I downgrade pyparsing to solve this issue temporarily?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had install the newest pyparsing(2.1.3) and this issue is fixed !

Answer (score 2):

I had install the newest pyparsing(2.1.3) and this issue is fixed !

Download page: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyparsing/2.1.3